# Attaching terminal lugs to conductive case

Tags: resistance, conductivity, industrial

I am wondering if there is a standard way to attach terminal lugs to a case that is conductive. I want to create an electrical connection that is mechanically connected with a screw. The issues with that are that the case I want to screw into features a lower resistance than the load. The next problem concerns the load itself, which is nichrome resistance wire that reaches high temperatures.

Essentially what I am wondering is: how do toasters and other commercial products that use resistance wire make a connection that doesn't short and can handle the high temperatures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this: -

[image]

Image from [Screwfix](https://www.screwfix.com/p/hylec-32a-2-pole-terminal-block-5-pack/70278?kpid=70278&ds_rl=1249401&gclid=CjwKCAiAjPyfBhBMEiwAB2CCIjFTvDyzpVZDwIeGPRQ1eb-_-nhChNiGym7ibrRVZCkpAgRWTLi8GBoCbCgQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) and it's rated at 32 amps and 450 volts AC.

**Google image search phrase**: ceramic connector for heater

Answer (score 1):

Grounded ring terminal lugs are commonly screwed to tapped hole in an anti-corrosion plated steel case or welded threaded studs to painted cases with 2 nuts to utilize the threads for conductivity.

The total resistance from a ground pin on the plug to case only needs to be less than 100 milliohms to satisfy UL for safety.

Toaster NiCr flat wire uses high pressure crimp connections to high temp braided insulated wire.

The voltage insulations were done with thin sheets of Mica to form the spaced wires to reach approx. 550’C max at nominal voltage.

When the case is double insulated inside then only a 2 pin plug is needed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen, they use larger lugs. A larger lug allows for more thermal transfer into the chassis if it's heating up from contact resistance and a larger lug also reduces contact resistance by increasing surface area.

Another thing I have seen is multiple lugs for higher current.